# how do I make only one element visible using the same function

Tags: function, visibility, display, hidden

I am trying to set up a frequently asked questions page. I could assign each question so a seperate function and store the answer in my HTML and display as hidden, then the event will trigger the function to make the hidden answer appear. I am trying to find a way to use the same functions to achieve this. This is what i have so far with example text included. What is happeneing at the moment is if i click on the first question , all the answer appear at once, i obvously dont want this and want one answer to appear at a time, thanks

```
     <script>
 
      function displayAnswer () { 

var getParent = document.getElementsByClassName("questions");
var getParentNode = getParent[0];
var child = getParentNode.childNodes[3];
child.style.visibility = "visible";

var getParent = document.getElementsByClassName("questions");
var getParentNode = getParent[1];
var child = getParentNode.childNodes[3];
child.style.visibility = "visible";

var getParent = document.getElementsByClassName("questions");
var getParentNode = getParent[2];
var child = getParentNode.childNodes[3];
child.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

What happens if i want to buy an items 
          this cost 600 pounds but we offer dis counts 
         
  
         
          What happens if i want to buy an items 
          this cost 600 pounds but we offer dis counts 
         
  
  
         
          What happens if i want to buy an items 
          this cost 600 pounds but we offer dis counts

Answer (score 0):

i have worked thisout now , by using the keyword this and then passing the function

```
     function displayAnswer (element)

     element.parentNode.secondElementChild.style.visibility= "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as requested:

```js
document.getElementById('allquestions').onclick=function(ev) { 
  let child=ev.target;   // get clicked element
  if(child.tagName=='P' && Array.prototype.indexOf.call(child.parentNode.children,child)==0) 
    child.nextElementSibling.style.display="block";
}
```

```css
#allquestions div p:nth-child(2) {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="allquestions">
  
    <div>
    <p>Click on first</p>
     <p> this cost 400 pounds but we offer dis counts </p>
     </div>
  
     <div>
     <p>second item,</p>
     <p>this cost 500 pounds but we offer dis counts </p>
     </div>
  
  
     <div>
     <p>Third item</p>
     <p>this cost 600 pounds but we offer dis counts </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I shortened both, your html and script parts to the bare minimum.

**Explanation:**
The click event is defined as a "deferred" event. I. e. the `onclick` attribute of the parent `<div id="allquestions">` is set to become the click handler for all questions. This is advantageous for dynamically created (growing) pages as I do not need to assign the click handler individually. Inside the handler function I check which element received the click and only unfold the action if it was

- a `<p>` element and
- if it was the first child of another element.

This second check is done with: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(child.parentNode.children,child)==0`. The index of element `child` in a collection of DOM elements (`child.parentNode.children`) is calculated by calling the Array-method `indexOf()`. The `.call()` method performs the trick of applying the `Array.prototype` function on the collection `child.parentNode.children`. Alternatively I could have done this:

```
[...child.parentNode.children].indexOf(child)==0
```

The spread operator in `[...collection]` turns the collection into a proper array from of which I can then use the `.indexOf` method.

Comment: thanks, im not quite there yet in fully understanding your code but can appreciate the simplicity of it , thanks for reply